# Подсчет посетителей находящихся на поддоменах

Tags: php

Есть скрипт вывода онлайн посетителей на сайте. Как добавить в него подсчет посетителей находящихся на поддоменах (их несколько)?

Например: domain.com + ru.domain.com + be.domain.com = Всего Посетителей онлайн.

```
<?php
session_start(); 

function GetUsersOnline(){ 
clearstatcache(); 
$SessionDir = session_save_path(); 
$Timeout = 60 * 3; 
if ($Handler = scandir ($SessionDir)){ 
$count = count ($Handler); 
$users = 0; 

for ($i = 2; $i < $count; $i++){ 
if (time() - fileatime ($SessionDir . '/' . $Handler[$i]) < $Timeout){ 
$users++; 
} 
} 

return $users; 
} else { 
return 'error'; 
} 
} 

echo 'Онлайн: ' . GetUsersOnline();   
?>
```

Comment: А для чего еще, кроме подсчета посетителей на сайте, у вас используются сессии?

Comment: Только подсчет посетителей на сайте.

Comment: Тогда вам действительно проще всего будет объединить сессии, как советует @EvgeniyBudanov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session_save_path можно указать программно

```
    ini_set('session.save_path','...путь...');
    session_start();
```

Если надо просто общая сумма - session_save_path для всех поддоменов должен быть одинаковый, и у вас всё уже готово
Если отдельно - для каждого сохраняйте сессии в разных директориях, и в скрипте подсчитывайте кол-во сессий в каждой

Comment: Прошу уточнить, как программно это сделать?

Comment: ini_set('session.save_path','...путь...');  session_start();

Comment: Папка должна быть на сервере. Путь прописал. + Скрипт установить на всех поддоменах. Все Правильно? `ini_set('session.save_path','/tmp');
    session_start();`